# How do you make links clickable in Tilda terminals in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, tilda

In Ubuntu 20.04 HTTP URLs like `http://example.com` are not clickable anymore in the output of Tilda. This worked in Ubuntu 18.04 but I could not find a setting how to enable that.

I also tested the standard Ubuntu 20.04 Terminal and links are not clickable there either. At least the URL is underlined there when I hover with the mouse over it but clicking does not do anything.

How do you make URL links clickable in terminals generally and how in Tilda specifically?

Comment: Update tilda from the upstream git repo, see https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda/issues/406. Also you have to Ctrl+click or similar in probably in all the terminals, not just simply click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug and has been solved now by an update of Tilda in the official Ubuntu 20.04 sources. A normal system update with `apt` solved it for me.